# Accessing self-hosted service binding to public IP address

Tags: c#, wcf, amazon-web-services

We have a WCF service we are trying to self-host (not IIS) on an AWS instance. There's an STS and a service host running as separate windows services both on the same machine. Users should be able to access the service from different geographic locations/domains so we won't be using windows security.

The endpoints and base address are defined in the app.config which are read at startup. IP addresses are used, no hostnames.

The problem we are having is that the service is not accessible from an outside source (firewall disabled). The service host won't start if the public ip address is used so the services are configured to use the private IP address, but it seems the private IP address is passed back to the client which obviously won't work. My question is, what kinds of configuration changes should we be looking into to make the service accessible? Do we need a custom metadata provider?

The server has a certificate installed. There are some security requirements for transferring data, so `ws2007HttpBinding`, `ws2007FederationHttpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding` and `ws2007HttpBinding` are used.

A few examples:

Bind to public AWS hostname (ec2-54-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com) which is the same as binding to public IP address -- STS starts but service host fails with

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
```

Is there a trust issue for the public IP address?

Bind to private IP address:

```
There was no endpoint listening at https://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:6040/MySTS/UsernameOverTransport that could accept the message
```

which makes sense because the private IP address is ... private.

I tried configuring the bindings with `hostNameComparisonMode="Exact / WeakWildcard / StrongWildcard"` but that didn't seem to make a difference. Also made sure `<message>` has `establishSecurityContext="false"` with no change as well.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Amazon support. What happens if you build a quick IIS-hosted website and drop in a Test.HTML file? Can you access that from outside? If so, you've probably got a config issue in your WCF service, if not, you've got a rights or DNS problem, it would seem to me.